# Критика кода JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, инспекция-кода

Здравствуйте, я только начинаю разрабатывать на js и решил сделать некий тренировочный проект. Хотел бы получить критику, замечания и помарки по даному коду.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'); //taking canvas by id
ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

var pText = document.getElementById('score');

document.addEventListener("keydown", keyPush);
document.addEventListener("keydownCreate", keyPush);

ctx.fillStyle = "DarkGreen";
ctx.fillRect( 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
//-----------------------------------------------------------

var step = 35;                   //cells size

var score = 0;      //really score

var maxX = canvas.width-step;    //border for creating meal
var maxY = canvas.height-step;
var min = 0;

var meal = 0;                    //flag(meal existing) ...(in future meal count)
mealx = 0;                       //meal x pos
mealy = 0;

var key = "";      //keycode

var brd = 5;      //border to make snake cells smaller than another objects
var tail = 3;      //tail size
var pos = [];       //tail position (pos[0] - head)
var px = 0, py = 0;     //new head position
var bigHead = 0;     //flag to make another head after eating 

var time = 90;      //timer delay

for(var i = 0; i < tail; i++){  //pushing start tail
 pos.push([i*step, 0]);
}


function game(){
 //clear canvas
 ctx.fillStyle = "DarkGreen";
 ctx.fillRect( 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
 key = "right";
 //start timer
 var timerId = setInterval(function() {
  if(key == "esc"){//exit   
   clearInterval(timerId);
   ctx.fillStyle = "red";
   ctx.fillRect( 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
   alert("game over");
  }
  if(key == "left" || key == "up" || key == "down" || key == "right"){//newt move
   newMeal();
   changePos();
   draw();
  }
 }, time);
}
function changePos(){//changing elements position
 for(var i = 1; i < tail; i++){
  if(pos[i][0]==pos[0][0] && pos[i][1] == pos[0][1]){
   for(var j = 3; j < tail; j++){
    pos[i].pop();
   } 
   tail = 3;
   score = 0;
  }
 }
 if(pos[0][0] == mealx && pos[0][1] == mealy){//eating 
  score++;
  meal = 0;
  tail++;
  bigHead = 1;
  pos.push([0, 0]);
 }
 for(var i = tail-1; i >= 1; i--){//new tail position
  pos[i][0] = pos[i-1][0];
  pos[i][1] = pos[i-1][1];
 }
 if(px == pos[0][0] && py == pos[0][1]){//if no changes
  if(key == "left")px-=step;
  if(key == "right")px+=step;
  if(key == "up")py-=step;
  if(key == "down")py+=step;
 }

 if(px<0)px = canvas.width-step;//new head position
 if(py<0)py = canvas.height-step;
 if(px>canvas.width-step)px = 0;
 if(py>canvas.height-step)py = 0;
 pos[0][0]=px;
 pos[0][1]=py;
}
function newMeal(){
 if(meal==0){//if no meal
  mealx = Math.floor(Math.random() * (maxX - min) + min);//new position
  mealy = Math.floor(Math.random() * (maxY - min) + min);
  
  while(mealx%step){//center
   mealx+=1;
  }
  while(mealy%step){
   mealy+=1;
  }
  meal = 1;//flag(there is meal)
 }
}
function draw(){//drawing canvas
 pText.innerHTML = "Score: " + score;

 ctx.fillStyle = "DarkGreen";//claer canvas
 ctx.fillRect( 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

 if(meal != 0){//draw meal  
  ctx.fillStyle = "red";
  ctx.fillRect( mealx, mealy, step-brd, step-brd);
 }
 
 if(bigHead == 0){//drawing head
  ctx.fillStyle = "lime";
  ctx.fillRect(pos[0][0], pos[0][1], step-brd, step-brd);
  ctx.fillStyle = "DarkGreen";
  ctx.fillRect(pos[0][0]+step/7, pos[0][1]+step/7, step/1.8, step/1.8 ); 
 }else{
  ctx.fillStyle = "yellow";
  ctx.fillRect(pos[0][0], pos[0][1], step-brd, step-brd);
  ctx.fillStyle = "red";
  ctx.fillRect(pos[0][0]+step/7, pos[0][1]+step/7, step/1.8, step/1.8 );
  bigHead++;
  if(bigHead == 5){
   bigHead = 0;
  }
 }

 //drawing tail
 var clrG = 255;
 var clrR = 0;
 var str = "rgb(0, ";
 for(var i = 1; i < tail; i++){
  if(clrG<=0){
   ctx.fillStyle = "rgb("+clrR+", 0, 0)";
   clrR+=20;
  }
  else{
   ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(0, "+clrG+", 0)";
   clrG -= 20;
  }
  
  ctx.fillRect(pos[i][0], pos[i][1], step-brd, step-brd);
 } 
}
function keyPush(evt){//key codes
 if(evt.keyCode == 37){
  if(key != "right" && key != "left"){//to avoid turn around and to avoid *jumping* through cells
   key = "left";
   px-=step;//changing head position
  }  
 }
 if(evt.keyCode == 38){
  if(key != "down" && key != "up"){
   key = "up";
   py-=step;
  }
 }
 if(evt.keyCode == 39){
  if(key != "left" && key != "right"){
   key = "right";
   px+=step;
  }
 }
 if(evt.keyCode == 40){
  if(key != 'up' && key != "down"){
   key = "down";
   py+=step;
  }
 } 
 if(evt.keyCode == 27){
  key = "esc";
 }
 if(evt.keyCode == 13){
  key = "enter";
 }
}
function upButton(){
 if(key != "down" && key != "up"){
  key = "up";
  py-=step;
 }
}
function downButton(){
 if(key != 'up' && key != "down"){
  key = "down";
  py+=step;
 }
}
function leftButton(){
 if(key != "right" && key != "left"){
  key = "left";
  px-=step;
 } 
}
function rightButton(){
 if(key != "left" && key != "right"){
  key = "right";
  px+=step;
 }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>SnakeQQ</title>
 <style type="text/css">
  input{
   margin:10px;
   width:50px;
   height:40px;
  }
  .control{
   width:100px;
   height:60px;
  }
  p{
   text-align: -webkit-center;
   font-size:40px;
   margin: 0px;
  }

 </style>
</head>
<body>
 <p id="score">
  Score: 0
 </p>
 <div style="display: -webkit-inline-box">
  <canvas id="canvas" width="1050" height="560" ></canvas>
  <div>
   <div style="text-align: -webkit-center">
    <input type="button" id="play" value="play" onClick="game()"/>
    <!--<input type="button" id="map" value="create map" onClick="construct()"/>-->
   </div>
   <div style="text-align: -webkit-center">
    <div>
     <input class="control" type="button" id="up" value="up" onClick="upButton()"/>
    </div>
    <div>
     <input class="control" type="button" id="left" value="left" onClick="leftButton()"/>
     <input class="control" type="button" id="right" value="right" onClick="rightButton()"/>
    </div>
    <div>
     <input class="control" type="button" id="down" value="down" onClick="downButton()"/>
    </div>
    
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js" ></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: let и const вместо var, не объявлять переменные в глобальной области видимости

Comment: Нигде нет отступов! Срочно править!

Comment: Описание метки надо бы вам почитать: Вопросы по этой метке должны содержать только работающий код . Если у вас вопрос "почему не работает" — не ставьте эту метку. Обязательно **ОПИШИТЕ РЕАЛИЗУЕМУЮ ФУНКЦИОНАЛЬНОСТЬ И НАЗНАЧЕНИЕ КОДА**. Используйте стандартный для языка стиль кодирования — имена функций и переменных, отступы, пробелы и прочее. Подробная инструкция есть в полном описании.`

Comment: @stackflow у нас тут филиал CR на русском языке.

Comment: @stackflow в отдельном сайте пока нет большой необходимости.

Comment: @Vitaliy В начале документа можно добавить дириктиву [use strict](https://learn.javascript.ru/strict-mode) для проверки на соответствие стандарту. Использовать только один тип кавычек или двойные или одинарные. Длинные условия можно выносить в отдельную функцию. Определиться с отступами между функциями. В идеале, стоит прочитать какую-нибудь книгу, на подобии "Совершенный код" Макконнелла или ее, а также поизучать javascript best practices. И ознакомиться со [справкой](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) о том, как задавать вопросы на stackowerflow.